# Analycity of power function

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show that the function $f(z)=z^k$ is not analytic if $k$ is not integer?

How to show that $f(x)=(a+z)^{-1}$, $a>0$ real is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-a\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on which tools and definitions you're using.

The easy way out with powerful tools is to note that $f(x) = x^k$ is analytic on $\mathbb R^+$ and therefore there's a analytic continuation of it into $\mathbb C$ and let's call this continuation $f(z) = z^k$ (as the definition of $z^k$). Then of course $f(z)$ is analytic (wherever it's defined).

Another solution would be to define $z^k = e^{k \ln z}$, which in turn would reduce the problem into showing that $\ln$ is analytic and scaling an anylitic yields an analytic ($k\ln z$ being analytic) and exponentiation of an analytic is analytic. The latter two can be shown using the chain rule and the fact that if a function is derivable then it's analytic. The first is to use the fact that $\ln$ is the inverse of $e^z$ and therefore use the fact that the inverse of a derivable function is derivable unless the derivate of the original function is $0$.

In both cases you need to be aware that $z^k$ becomes multivalued. You explicitely know that in the second case since $\ln$ is multivalued and in the first approach there's no guarantee that the analytic continuation will become singlevalued.